# How do you go to the previous route in iron-router?

Tags: google-chrome, meteor, iron-router, chrome-ios, ios-web-app

I'm using an event handler to go to the previous URL/route:

```
'click #back': ->
  history.back()
```

This works in Chrome desktop, Chrome devtools mobile device view, and in Safari on a physical device itself (iOS 8.1.2), but not in Chrome on the device. Behavior is:

- Load /
- Click link to /foo
- URL changes to /foo, and foo template renders
- Click #back
- URL changes to / briefly, then changes back to /foo. The page body does not change. (Correct behavior is the URL permanently changes to /, and the / templates are rendered, without a page load.)
- Click #back second time
- / is reloaded from server

Is this a mobile Chrome problem, or should I be using some iron-router API like `Router.back()`?

Comment: Using `history.back()` [should work](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/48) (at least some years ago :P).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`history.back()` is the method supported by `iron-router`, it just appears there's a problem with iOS Chrome.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working for Meteor sAlert module when I want to preserve the alert for another page

Comment: Sorry, unfamiliar with sAlert