# Return to previous path using MeteorJS and Iron Routing

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Using the latest Meteor and Iron Routing, how do I simply "go back" to the previous route? I feel silly even asking, because it seems this would be a main feature of Iron Routing..

For instance, say I went to "/contacts" from "/posts" and then I wanted to "go back" with my app's back button (not the browser button, though this does what I'd like this functionality to do) to /contacts again because that was the last route I was on. Is there not a one-line command for this such as Router.back() that I could put in a global routes file whenever this is triggered?

This seems like it would be a very common question, yet I can't find anyone that has asked it yet.. If so, forgive me and please direct me with a link.

Comment: window.history.back() ? ;)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27455173/how-do-you-go-to-the-previous-route-in-iron-router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FooController.events({
    'click [data-action=back]' : function () {
        history.back();
      }
});
```

Sorry, I was looking for something like the above code, which I put into [InsertGlobalControllerName]Controller.Events()

I wanted to make it a global event so a back button could work on all layouts. I figured it out, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

To go back in `iron-router`, just use:

```
history.go(-1)
```

*or*

```
history.back()
```

Both of these are supported by `iron-router`.